# ¿Cómo puedo optimizar este código en menos de dos segundos?

Tags: java, bucle-for, condiciones, bucles, optimización

Necesito ayuda para optimizar este codigo, al imprimirlo dura mas o menos 3 segundos, El programa ya esta terminado, hace correctamente la salida todo esta bien solo necesito la optmizacion, necesito es que imprima o haga los calculos en programa en menos de dos segundos aqui esta el problema: https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/231/A

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
     import java.io.IOException;
     import java.io.InputStreamReader;

     public class Team {

       public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int Petya, Vasya, Tonya , Suma , Conteo=0;
        int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            Petya = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            Vasya = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            Tonya = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            Suma = Petya + Vasya + Tonya;
            if (Suma>=2)  {
                Conteo++;
            }
        System.out.println(Conteo);
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Tu pregunta es igual a la que cerre anteriormente y tiene el mismo problema. Este codigo es correcto, y deberia ser instantaneo a menos que tenga algun problema oculto donde lo pruebas (o tengas miles de inputs).. estas seguro que el problema esta por ahi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema no es el tiempo de ejecución sino que no funciona. Agrego el código con las correcciones enumeradas:

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    
    public class Test {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            int Petya, Vasya, Tonya , Suma , Conteo= 0;
    
            int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    
                // 2. cada línea contiene 3 números separados por espacios
                // así que se deben extraer uno a uno para convertirlos a enteros
                // eso se hace haciendo un split a la línea
                String[] numeros = br.readLine().split(" ");
                
                
                // 3. convertir los 3 números a enteros
    
                // el primer numero esta en la posicion 0 y así
                Petya = Integer.parseInt(numeros[0]);
                Vasya = Integer.parseInt(numeros[1]);
                Tonya = Integer.parseInt(numeros[2]);
    
                Suma = Petya + Vasya + Tonya;
    
                if (Suma >= 2 )  {
                    Conteo++;
                }
    
            }
    
            // 1. La impresión del resultado debe ir al final
            System.out.println(Conteo);
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: gracias bro merci